# What is the interpretation of $\nu(dy - x)$ where $\nu$ is a Lévy measure?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, levy-processes

In a paper I am reading, it is seemingly suggested that, if $\nu(dx)$ is a Lévy measure, then the following holds for a function $f(x)$ which is smooth (and satsifies some integrability conditions):
$$
\int^{-x}_{-\infty}f(x)\,\nu(\mathrm dy) + \int^0_{-\infty}[f(y)-f(x)]\, \nu(\mathrm dy-x) = \int^{-x}_{-\infty}f(x+y)\, \nu(\mathrm dy)
$$
I would like to verify this equation but I am not sure how.

I think my main problem is understanding what $\nu(\mathrm dy-x)$ means. I understand the basic behaviour of a Lévy measure, but I have not seen a case like this before. I suspect it might have something to do with convolutions of measures? I would appreciate if someone could verify this before I potentially set out on learning about them, and it would be fantastic if it also can be shown how it works in the context of that equation.

Source of equation: [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.03501v1.pdf). The equation can be obtained after some manipulations of the expression on p 11, under "Step 4".

Comment: Simply a matter of notation: for every measure $\mu$, $$\int f(y)\mu(\mathrm dy-x)=\int f(y+x)\mu(\mathrm dy).$$

Comment: @Did Many thanks. I assume we also need to change the limits, i.e.
$$
\int^{y=b}_{y=a} f(y)\nu(\mathrm dy - x) = \int^{y=b-x}_{y=a-x} f(y +x)\nu(\mathrm dy) 
$$